# How to create the JVM option for XX\:OnOutOfMemoryError using payara server docker POSTBOOT_COMMANDS

Tags: java, docker-compose, jvm, jvm-arguments, payara

## Issue

I'm trying to add the jvm option for `XX\:OnOutOfMemoryError` so the value is shown in double quotes, like so:

```
-XX:OnOutOfMemoryError="kill -9 %p"
```

but when I come to `list-jvm-options` it appears without the quotes, like so:

```
-XX:OnOutOfMemoryError=kill -9 %p
```

To create the option, I use the command:

```
create-jvm-options -- -XX\:OnOutOfMemoryError="kill -9 %p"
```

Things i've tried:

```
create-jvm-options -- -XX\:OnOutOfMemoryError="kill -9 %p"
create-jvm-options -- -XX\:OnOutOfMemoryError=""kill -9 %p""
create-jvm-options -- -XX\:OnOutOfMemoryError="""kill -9 %p"""
create-jvm-options -- -XX\:OnOutOfMemoryError=\"kill -9 %p\"
create-jvm-options -- -XX\:OnOutOfMemoryError="\"kill -9 %p\""
create-jvm-options -- -XX\:OnOutOfMemoryError='"kill -9 %p"'
create-jvm-options -- -XX\:OnOutOfMemoryError=^"kill -9 %p^"
create-jvm-options -- -XX\:OnOutOfMemoryError="^"kill -9 %p^""
```

These error with:

`org.glassfish.common.util.admin.UnacceptableValueException: Invalid parameter: jvm_option_name.  This parameter may not have more than one value`

## Reason

I'm trying to port an older Vangrant setup over to Docker.
The Vagrant image uses contos7. Doing `asadmin list-jvm-options` on the Vagrant image returns:

```
-XX:OnOutOfMemoryError="kill -9 %p"
```

Which is what i'm looking to recreate.

I'm not 100% sure if the double quotes surrounding  `kill -9 %p` matter, but I want to replicate it as close as possible.

## To re-create

I'm running payara from docker-compose, using 3 files:

### docker-compose.yaml

```
version: '3.1'

services:
  payara:
    restart: always
    build: payara/.
    ports:
      - 8090:8080
      - 4848:4848
```

### Dockerfile

```
FROM payara/server-full:5.2021.5
COPY post-boot-commands.asadmin $POSTBOOT_COMMANDS
```

### post-boot-commands.asadmin

```
enable-secure-admin
create-jvm-options -- -client
set server.http-service.access-logging-enabled=true
set server.thread-pools.thread-pool.http-thread-pool.max-thread-pool-size=128
set server.ejb-container.property.disable-nonportable-jndi-names="true"
set configs.config.server-config.network-config.protocols.protocol.http-listener-2.http.request-timeout-seconds=-1
set server.http-service.access-log.format=common
create-jvm-options -- -XX\:OnOutOfMemoryError="kill -9 %p"
```

using the file structure:

```
- docker-compose.yaml
  paraya/
     - Dockerfile
     - post-boot-commands.asadmin
```

Once you've run `docker-compose up`, you can bash into the container using:

```
docker exec -it docker_payara_1 bash
```

With `docker_payara_1` being the name of the container.

Once in, you can list the JVM options by:

```
asadmin list-jvm-options
```

default user: admin

default password: admin

Documentation for payara server docker overview [here](https://docs.payara.fish/community/docs/documentation/ecosystem/docker-images/server-image-overview.html)

Documentation for `create-jvm-options` [here](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E26576_01/doc.312/e24938/create-jvm-options.htm#GSRFM00042)

Comment: Use `-XX:+ExitOnOutOfMemoryError` instead

Comment: i guess if `restart: unless-stopped` is set on the container then it should restart on error?

Comment: I'm struggling to answer is one, i've moved on and am using `-XX:+ExitOnOutOfMemoryError` as recommended. Do the quotes around the command returned from `list-jvm-options` even matter?